# unicodedecodeerror 'ascii' codec error in wxPython

Tags: python, unix, wxpython, robotframework

I am getting an error

> unicodedecodeerror 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1
>   ordinal not in range(128)

while performing the below mentioned operation.

I have a program that reads files from remote machine(Ubuntu) using grep and cat command for the same to fetch values and stores the value in a variable via robot framework builtin keyword `export command from client`.

Following are the versions i am using:-
Robot Framework: 2.8.11
Ride: 0.55
Putty: 0.63
Pyhton: 2.7.3

I am doing a SSH session on Linux machine and on that machine their is a file in which the data is having accented characters for eg: **Õ Ü Ô Ý** .
While reading the text from the file containing accented characters using 'grep' and 'cat' command i am facing this issue.

> unicodedecodeerror 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1
>   ordinal not in range(128)

Thank you.

Comment: Mentioned below are the commands through which i am fetching the firstname and last name value from vcard and gettng the error.
"unicodedecodeerror 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1 ordinal not in range(128)"

${GetFirstname}   Execute Command From Client  cat ${con1}}|grep "^N:"|cut -d ":" -f2|cut -d ";" -f2                 
${GetLastname}    Execute Command From Client  cat ${con1}|grep "^N:"|cut -d ":" -f2|cut -d ";" -f1                                                                   

The data file by which vcard is getting generated is having the data as:- N:íóñ;ákshat

Comment: `export command from client` is not a built-in keyword, so it's hard for us to know what it's doing. Does that keyword come from your own company, or does it come from some other external library?

Comment: My apologies, The "execute command from client" is a user defined keyword. 
In my project i am using this operation to execute the combination of cat and grep commands(mentioned in my previous comments) over existing SSH session(unix one).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the file contains UTF-8, not ASCII.  Robot Framework appears to be expecting ASCII text.  ASCII text only contains values in the range 0-127, when the ascii codec sees a byte 0xC3 it throws an error.  (If the text was using the Western European Windows 8-bit encoding, 0xC3 would be Ã.  If it was using the MacOS encoding, 0xC3 would be ∑.  In fact, it is the first of two bytes which define a single character in the range of most of the interesting accented characters.)

Somehow, you need to teach Robot Framework to use the correct encoding.